# PHP sdk redirect after he have granted permission

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I don't have very good skills in coding what i want to do is when i user visit my site and after he grant access to my app message will be posted to his wall and i want him to be redirected to some other url the wall post is working fine but after he grant permissions nothing happens only white page is shown this is the code what i have:

```
    <?php
require_once "./src/facebook.php";

$app_id = "xxxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxxx";

// Init facebook api.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));

// Get the url to redirect for login to facebook
// and request permission to write on the user's wall.
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array('scope' => 'publish_stream')
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);


// If not authenticated, redirect to the facebook login dialog.
// The $login_url will take care of redirecting back to us
// after successful login.
if (! $facebook->getUser()) {
    echo <<< EOT
<script type="text/javascript">
top.location.href = "$login_url";
</script>;
EOT;

    exit;
}

// Do the wall post.
$facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", array(
    message => "test",
    picture => "http://s.ytimg.com/yt/img/doodles/teachers_day_yoodle-vflBKh2mG.png",
    link => "http://www.youtube.com/",
    name => "test",
    caption => "test"
));
?>
```

Comment: where did you get $params? it looks like you copy pasted code snippets from different places
check facebook's documentation. There's a couple of examples there too

Answer (score 1):

to redirect a user after granting permissions use this:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();


if($user){
    // Get logout URL
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}else{
    // Get login URL
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope'         => 'publish_actions',
        'redirect_uri'  => 'http://mysite.com/success.html', //redirect user to this url
        ));
}
```